# Facebook Developer APIs - Trying to fetch all the campaigns, Adsets and Ads

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is what I'm trying to do -

The first GET request is to https://graph.facebook.com//<ACT_ID>/campaigns, which successfully returns me all the campaigns (Ofcourse I've handled pagination using the cursors provided)

The next step I perform is, for every campaign ID, I make a GET request to https://graph.facebook.com//<CAMPAIGN_ID>/adsets to fetch the respective adsets.

Here is where things go wrong. I get back an error which says `limit (#17) User request limit reached` after a few requests.

I have also tried using batch requests. But it appears as if the batch requests are in turn making individual multiple calls internally, which is again ending up in the request limit error.

Can anyone help me figure out how I can achieve this ? Bypass the limit or perhaps a different approach.

Thanks.

Please let me know if you need clarification on my question.

[UPDATE] : I have tried looking at the metrics from the header of an GET insights call. The CPU usage/call count/total time are way below the limits specified in the documentations. I have no idea why the request limit error is showing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to fetch campaigns, adsets and ads in a single call.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<ACT_ID>/campaigns?fields=id,name,adsets{id,name},ads{adset_id,name}
```

This will return an array of campaigns, with each campaign having arrays of adsets and ads that belong to it.

Now that I got the data, I can easily parse it according to the format I want which is each element in the array of campaigns having a array of adsets that belong to it. Each element in this array of adsets having an array of ads that belong to it.